# Double/Random alias name in select clause on Oracle 11g does not throw invalid identifier exception

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Yesterday I stumbled upon some strange behavior on a customers Oracle 10g instance. Some procedure I wrote gave me an `invalid identifier` exception but was running fine on my Oracle 11g instances.

The relevant query was something like the following:

```
select b.b.v_col_b 
from tbla a
left join tblb b on a.pk_col_a = b.fk_a;
```

Pleas note the **`b.b.v_col_b`** part of the query. Changing from `left join` to `inner join` did finally raise a `ORA-00904: "B"."B"."V_COL_B": invalid identifier` exception, but:

1. Isn't this a syntax error?
2. Can somebody explain this behaviour?

A working demo can be found on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/530a4/6)

Edit: Added the table definition:

```
create table tbla (
  pk_col_a int primary key, 
  v_col_a varchar2(50));

create table tblb (
  pk_col_b int primary key, 
  fk_a int, 
  v_col_b varchar2(50));
```

Edit2: As @LalitKumarB's mentioned this only seems to happen on Oracle 11g

Comment: It also selects: `select k.b.v_col_b 
from tbla a
left join tblb b on a.pk_col_a = b.fk_a;`  Weird

Comment: So you have a column named `b.v_col_b`?

Comment: @Arion, nope, see fiddle...

Comment: @Jajob Are you sure the query works fine on `12c`? Because both the queries certainly throws `Invalid identifier` on my 12c instance. Exact version is `12.1.0.1`.

Comment: I see the same behaviour on 10.2.0.5 and 11.2.0.3; the outer join 'works', the inner join gets the error. What patch level do you see it fail on in 10g? Or does your real query behave even more strangely than the demo?

Comment: @AlexPoole Currently i cannot check the 10g instance, i'll do as soon as i can access it again. The demo query is almost the same as the production one, there are only three more tables and one subselect involved.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Thanks, I just checked my 12c instance and it throws ´Invalid identifier´, I edited my question

Comment: @Jakob I tested it on `11.2.0.2` and I see similar results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations, you have found a bug :)

In that particular case you can write whatever you want when selecting any of the tblb columns:

```
select helloworld.b.v_col_b, mghjfghj.b.fk_a, asdasdas.b.pk_col_b
from tbla a
left join tblb b on a.pk_col_a = b.fk_a;
```

You can even do it with a right join:

```
select helloworld.b.v_col_b, mghjfghj.b.fk_a, asdasdas.b.pk_col_b
from tblb b
right join tbla a on a.pk_col_a = b.fk_a;
```

It won't work with the Oracle join syntax ( (+) notation ) though.

It is not an expected behaviour and, as Lalit noted in the comments, is fixed in 12C. You can file a bug request wit Oracle Support if you want. Maybe there is already a patch for it.

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-00904: "B"."B"."V_COL_B": invalid identifier

In SQL the *qualified identifier* X.Y.Z relates at a scheme X, table Y, and column Z. Whereas a simple Y.Z means table Y, column Z.

And then calling X.Y.Z an identifier might be misleading too, but not too irregular in computer science.

*On the error behavior you did experience I cannot tell much.*